# Need help in aligning the Input label content using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How can we fix if label content is more than input box size? I want all the input box to be in same line and label should wrap accordingly?

[image]

I want to align as shown in the picture, but I was not able to do it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your issue when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to answer without seeing the code. It could be that the items are centered horizontally in the parent container with the following css style:

'align-items: center;'

try instead

'align-items: flex-end;'

to align the input boxes to the bottom of the parent container.